# What is the number of elements of upper sets in a finite power set?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Take any finite set $X$ with cardinality $|X|=n$. Let $P(X)$ denote the power set of $X$ ordered by inclusion.  Let $\uparrow\{x\}$ denote an [**upper set**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set) of $P(X)$, i.e. a subset $U$ such that if $\{x\}\subseteq p$ for $\{x\},p\in P(X)$, then $p\in U$.

What is the formula for calculating the number of elements of $U$, given the cardinality $n$ of $X$? Since for singleton $\{x\}$, $U$ is just an ultrafilter, its number of elements would be $2^{n-1}$. What if we take the upper set $\uparrow\{x,y\}$ for $x\neq y$, and similarly for more elements of $X$?

Comment: Each upper set looks a lot like a power set of its own.

Comment: I find this question confusing. Isn't $U$ just $\uparrow\{x\}$? And what do you mean "when $\{x\}$ is a singleton"? It is one! Also "The" upper set of $\mathcal P(X)$? There can be many upper sets.

Comment: @GitGud, yes, $\uparrow\{x\}=U$, just wanted to define it explicitly. I think my notation ${x}$ may have been sloppy - I wanted to include the notion of an upper set when ${x}={a,b}$, i.e. when $x$ is any collection of elements of $X$. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, given $A\subseteq X$ you're looking for the set
$$ {\uparrow}A = \{ B\in\mathcal P(X) \mid A\subseteq B \} $$
But this is the same set as
$$ \{ C\cup A \mid C\in\mathcal P(X\setminus A) \} $$
which (since adding $A$ to each of these $C$s is obviously an injective operation) has the same cardinality as $\mathcal P(X\setminus A)$, namely $2^{|X|-|A|}$.